# PHP Countdown | Starts when value created | When done, change another value

Tags: php, jquery, database, reset, countdown

I'm trying to create a timer with jQuery and PHP; the idea is pretty simple, yet I haven't found anything that suits my needs after two days of searching.

So far this is my timer script:

```js
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#ms_timer').countdowntimer({
            minutes :3,
            seconds : 0,
            size : "xl"
        });
    });
</script>
```

The current script is built with jQuery.

I need the timer to start when a value is created in the database.
And when the timer runs out, it needs to change a value in the database.

PHP and JavaScript/jQuery are still a tad new to me, so if any response could guide me toward my goal, I'd really appreciate it.

I'm the web designer, the other fella I'm working with is the main programmer, for databases and stuff; but if I can achieve creating this (with a little help), I might get the basics of how our technical stuff works.

Comment: Your wanting your javascript to 'know' when a value is created in the database?  That to me, means you'll need to implement something with websockets or javascript polling.  Otherwise, the frontend doesn't have a way of knowing when an event on the back end happens.

Comment: where is php code? better to show combination of that code with jQuery

Comment: Please post full code.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll read up on websockets and JS polling. - I don't have any written PHP code yet, as I wasn't sure what to put in it.

Comment: I think an ajax request to create it and another ajax request to update it would be a possible solution

Comment: Thanks xNeyte, I'll have a look at this.